# c# debugging visual studios 2012

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

is there a way to debug in visual studios 2012 whereby you want to start debugging when a certain variable reaches a certain value? I have a program thats iterating through a 2D array and changing values, but I want it to start debugging when my counters for the rows and columns get to a certain number, that way the information from the other cells in the array is already present bc their presence affects the values of the other cells.

Answer (score 3):

You can set conditional breakpoints.

Set a normal breakpoint, and then right-click on it and select "Condition..." . Enter the C# expression that you want to check for when to break.

This feature may not be available in all versions of VS, but it's at least available in VS2012 professional.

Alternatively, you can always just add an if statement:

```
if (some condition) {
    Console.WriteLine("Set breakpoint here");
}
```

Comment: so if i have counters i for rows and j for columns i can put break when (i=value && j=value)?

Comment: in the condition i put if i=value, j=value  but it throws an error

Comment: @user2521432: you must use C# syntax, so `i==value && j==value`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use conditional breakpoints if stated above, which is the easier way to go, or try to imitate the Data Breakpoints feature in C debugging, that stops execution when data is changed.
There is a full answer here:
[Reasking about hitting breakpoint at property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438485/reasking-about-hitting-breakpoint-at-property-setter/31861557#31861557)

The general idea is basically to wrap the access to your data in a field, and put a breakpoints on the setter method of the property.

There are some VS plugins that can make this easier for you, such as OZ Code.